# Not able to access the return of a function inside another function despite the console.log() showing me the correct value

Tags: javascript, html

1. I am trying to get the value of an input from a li element.
2. I am trying to make that value correspond to the name='' tag of a different  element
3. I am trying to get this all done dynamically with JS, in terms of, the `<input>` Element will be created with JS and then its name='' will be assigned through JS

Essentially the problem is, no matter in which way I call createMetafield(`${shopCode}`); $shopCode always returns as undefined, leaving the  elements like so: name='[key ${i} ***undefined***]'

How can I get my createMetafield() function to properly access the return of getShopName();

```js
//JS function for getting the value out of this html. This function works and is behaving as expected: 

function getShopName() {
  let langTab = document.querySelectorAll('.langTab');
  let acti = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
  let shopNameTest;
  langTab.forEach(lang => {
    lang.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
      Array.from(acti).forEach(act => {
        if (act.classList.contains('langTab')) {
          shopNameTest = act.childNodes[1].value;
          console.log(shopNameTest);

        }
      });
      return shopNameTest;
    });
  })
};

// Function which creates the new HTML element with the click of a button. 

function createMetafield(shopCode) {
  var i = 0;
  document.getElementById("createMetafield").addEventListener("click", () => {
    let container = document.createElement("div");
    let titleLabel = document.createElement("label");
    let bodyLabel = document.createElement("label");
    let textfieldTitle = document.createElement("input");
    let textfieldBody = document.createElement("textarea");
    let trashButton = document.createElement("i");
    let metafieldButton = document.getElementById("createMetafield");
    titleLabel.innerHTML = "Metafield Title:";
    bodyLabel.innerHTML = "Metafield Body:";
    textfieldTitle.name = `metafield[key ${i} ${shopCode}]`;
    textfieldBody.name = `metafield[value ${i} ${shopCode}]`;
    container.setAttribute("class", "formStyle form-group col-md-6");
    textfieldBody.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
    trashButton.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-trash");
    i++;
    console.log(i);
    titleLabel.appendChild(textfieldTitle);
    bodyLabel.appendChild(textfieldBody);
    bodyLabel.appendChild(trashButton);
    container.appendChild(titleLabel);
    container.appendChild(bodyLabel);
    metafieldButton.after(container);
  });
}
```

```html
<ul id="myTab1" class="nav nav-tabs bar_tabs right" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class='langTab'><a href="#tab_content11" id="home-tabb" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="false">FRANÇAIS</a><input type="hidden" name="shop[]" value="GWEUFR" readonly></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="langTab"><a href="#tab_content22" role="tab" id="profile-tabb" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-expanded="false">ENGLISH</a><input type="hidden" name="shop[]" value="GWEUEN" readonly></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="langTab"><a href="#tab_content33" role="tab" id="profile-tabb3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-expanded="true">DEUTSCH</a><input type="hidden" name="shop[]" value="GWEUDE" readonly></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="active langTab"><a href="#tab_content33" role="tab" id="profile-tabb3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-expanded="true">ALLGEMEIN</a><input type="hidden" name="shop[]" value="alg" readonly></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ive tried calling the function like this:  
var example = getShopName();

createMetafield(example);

I've tried storing $shopNameTest in a global 

I've tried createMetafield(getShopName());

all to no avail :((

Comment: Cheers for the formatting and thanks for the answer, I call createMetafield() after making the function

Comment: What do you expect `${shopCode}` to be?  It doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. Also returning a value from an event handler is (almost always) not meaningful, as the browser ignores most return values (except `false` to stop event propagation).

Comment: Where is createMetafield ? I do not see it in the HTML

Comment: Missing `</li>` aded

Comment: I expect $shopCode to be either GWEUDE, GWEUFR or GWEUEN as is the values from the inputs in the HTML.

Ah the browse ignores values returned from event handlers?

Comment: the id="createMetafield" is not in this HTML, because the function createMetafield() is correctly making the two inputs. the name='' element on the inputs that are created from createMetafield() have undefined in them.

Even though the getShopName(); is able to console.log() the value

Comment: `the id="createMetafield" is not in this HTML, ` Please add it since we need it to have a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan I am trying to implement your suggested improvement for getShopName(); function, thank you for that however, my current issue has been solved! :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your bug is that you are calling `return` inside one of these nested functions, that is not going to cause the parent function to return a value.

I suggest to use `for (const e of collection) { }` syntax rather than those nested lambda function things.  Here's doc on the new for syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: I could kick myself and kiss you! the for( const e of collection) loop did the trick because yes I suppose the return was getting lost in the nested loops?

Comment: for (const e of collection) is not an efficient method to get the code from the current active LI.

Comment: @BoogaBooga Yes, the `forEach` loops are functions themselves and could have a return value. That is why it is not an error to use `return` there. But the return inside `forEach` does not automatically cause the return value of the function, which called the `forEach`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thank you for the clarification :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this code - you are not actually using the found value

The click sets the active and the other click gets and creates

```js
const langTabs = document.querySelectorAll("#myTab1 .langTab")
document.getElementById("myTab1").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("li");
  if (tgt && tgt.classList.contains("langTab")) {
    langTabs.forEach(tab => tab.classList.remove("active"))
    tgt.classList.add("active")
  }
})


// Function which creates the new HTML element with the click of a button. 

document.getElementById("createMetafield").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const shopCode = document.querySelector(".langTab.active input").value
  var i = 0;

  let container = document.createElement("div");
  let titleLabel = document.createElement("label");
  let bodyLabel = document.createElement("label");
  let textfieldTitle = document.createElement("input");
  let textfieldBody = document.createElement("textarea");
  let trashButton = document.createElement("i");
  let metafieldButton = document.getElementById("createMetafield");
  titleLabel.innerHTML = "Metafield Title:";
  bodyLabel.innerHTML = "Metafield Body:";
  textfieldTitle.name = `metafield[key ${i} ${shopCode}]`;
  textfieldBody.name = `metafield[value ${i} ${shopCode}]`;
  container.setAttribute("class", "formStyle form-group col-md-6");
  textfieldBody.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
  trashButton.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-trash");
  i++;
  console.log(i);
  titleLabel.appendChild(textfieldTitle);
  bodyLabel.appendChild(textfieldBody);
  bodyLabel.appendChild(trashButton);
  container.appendChild(titleLabel);
  container.appendChild(bodyLabel);
  metafieldButton.after(container);
})
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<ul id="myTab1" class="nav nav-tabs bar_tabs right" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class='langTab'><a href="#tab_content11" id="home-tabb" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="false">FRANÇAIS</a><input type="hidden" name="shop[]" value="GWEUFR" readonly>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="langTab"><a href="#tab_content22" role="tab" id="profile-tabb" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-expanded="false">ENGLISH</a><input type="hidden" name="shop[]" value="GWEUEN" readonly>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="langTab"><a href="#tab_content33" role="tab" id="profile-tabb3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-expanded="true">DEUTSCH</a><input type="hidden" name="shop[]" value="GWEUDE" readonly></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="active langTab"><a href="#tab_content33" role="tab" id="profile-tabb3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-expanded="true">ALLGEMEIN</a><input type="hidden" name="shop[]" value="alg" readonly></li>
</ul>

<button id="createMetafield">Click</button>
```

Comment: Yes that also works! and that is what I wanted, cheers :)

Comment: @BoogaBooga I would say this is probably a more complete answer than the other answer

Comment: they are both the correct answer :) But I believe only 1 answer can be accepted no?

Comment: Also I do not agree you need a for..of at all

Comment: The accepted answer presented me with a solution, to change which type of loop I use (which worked). 
Your answer gave me code I could use which is awesome (and works). Therefore they are both the correct answer to my question

Comment: `const shopCode = document.querySelector(".langTab.active input").value` is the correct answer. You do not need a loop

Comment: Your method works 100% and its awesome thank you for it. But his method also works and it came in first.

Comment: I do not personally care, but using a for..in to get a value that can be called with one statement is not a good answer. I can come up with 10 different versions to get the value of the current hidden field, but the one I posted is the simplest, most direct and most performant answer. You can of course ignore recommended practises and do a loop

Comment: thanks for the feedback, once I am finished with the php side of this I will try to implement your answer as well for the meantime I am going with the currently selected answer though